# Two columns form on bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I don't know if this is possible. I want to do a two colums form where second column has a textarea, with my actual code i can only put inline with the rest of the form.
Something like this [mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Eei.png). I tried with form-row but it didn't work as expected.

HTML form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="formulario">
        <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3 col">
            <label for="tipo">Tipo:</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control ml-3" id="tipo" name="tipo" [(ngModel)]="asignatura.tipo" placeholder="Tipo">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3 col">
            <label for="categoria">Categoría:</label>
            <select class="custom-select ml-3" id="categoria" name="categoria" [(ngModel)]="asignatura.categoria" >
                <option *ngFor="let cat of categorias" name="categoria" [ngValue]="cat">{{cat.nombre}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3 col">
            <label for="formato">Formato:</label>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="radio"  class="form-check-input ml-4" id="formato" name="formato" value="Te&oacute;rica" [(ngModel)]="asignatura.formato">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="formato">
                    Teórica
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="radio"  class="form-check-input" id="formato2" name="formato" value="Pr&aacute;ctica" [(ngModel)]="asignatura.formato">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="formato">
                    Práctica
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3 col">
            <label for="codigo">Código:</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control ml-3" id="codigo" name="codigo" [(ngModel)]="asignatura.codigo" placeholder="Codigo">
        </div>
        <div class="float-right form-group mt-3 mb-3 col">
            <label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
            <textarea type="text" cols="23" rows="2" class="form-control ml-3" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" [(ngModel)]="asignatura.descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion"></textarea>
        </div> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya it is possible. You should use `form-row` class with a `form` tag.

inside of the form make two `divs` with the `col-*` you desire and it will work just fine as it works with `row`

Check out the following snippet I made it responsive too. If that's not what you need please let me know.

[image: result]

```css
:root {
  /* colors */
  --main-color: #2ecc71;
  --submit-hover: #1c9950;
}

.contact .my__form input[type="text"],
.contact .my__form input[type="email"],
.contact .my__form textarea {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.contact .my__form .textarea__group,
.contact .my__form textarea {
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .contact .my__form .textarea__group,
  .contact .my__form textarea {
    height: 200px;
  }
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--submit-hover);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus {
  font-weight: 500;
  outline: 1px solid var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="contact padding-top-bottom custom__outline text-center" id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="h2__style text-uppercase d-inline-block position-relative custom__underline mb-5" data-title="contact me">
      contact me
    </h2>
    <form class="my__form form-row mt-5 " method="POST" name="contact__main">
      <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact__main" />
      <p class="hidden">
        <label>
                        Don’t fill this out if you're human: <input name="bot-field" />
                    </label>
      </p>
      <div class=" col-lg-6 ">
        <div class="input-group ">
          <p class="hidden">
            <label>
                                Don’t fill this out if you're human:{" "}
                                <input name="bot-field" />
                            </label>
          </p>
          <label htmlFor="username" class="sr-only">
                            Your name
                        </label>
          <input class="w-100 my-2 form-control-lg" id="username" type="text" name="YourName" placeholder="Your Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label htmlFor="email" class="sr-only">
                            Email
                        </label>
          <input class="w-100 my-2 form-control-lg" id="email" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label htmlFor="subject" class="sr-only">
                            Subject
                        </label>
          <input class="w-100 my-2 form-control-lg mb-lg-0" id="subject" type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-lg-6 ">
        <div class="input-group h-100 textarea__group">
          <label htmlFor="message" class="sr-only">
                            message
                        </label>
          <textarea class="w-100 p-3 form-control-lg " id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group justify-content-start">
        <input class="m-1 my-2 custom__submit mt-5  " type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```